# dynamically create an image with image URL's

Tags: php, css, image, image-processing, dynamically-generated

I have a single decorated "picture frame" image with 5 blank boxes.

The user will provide 5 facebook picture URL's which will populate the 5 blank boxes.

I want to take the resulting "picture frame" populated with these 5 uploaded photos and generate a SINGLE image... with PHP/html/css/javascript... is this possible??

I already know that I can take the 5 URL's, upload them to a database and spit out the "template" image with the placeholder background-image source to be pulled from the picture URL's.  The problem is generating this SINGLE image... how can I do this?  please help!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP GD to generate an image from the 5 uploaded photos.

See [PHP GD Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)